# How to add character to each element in comma separated string

Tags: java, string

I have a string with a file extensions: "png,jpg,jpeg,tiff,bmp,cdr". I need to prepare it for accept attribute of input i.e something like that ".png,.jpg,.jpeg,.tiff,.bmp,.cdr".
How can I add dots to each element? I need the easiest and most elegant way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My elegant way is to have a Set instead of a string. Since you are receiving the data as a String, I have used Java 8 streams. I am doing the following:

1. Split the array using `","`
2. Prefix it with a `"."`
3. Collect it in a Set.

The sample code is as follows:

```
String x = "png,jpg,jpeg,tiff,bmp,cdr";
Set<String> extensions = Arrays.stream(x.split(",")).map(str -> "." + str).collect(Collectors.toSet());
System.out.println(extensions);
```

The output is:

```
[.bmp, .jpg, .cdr, .jpeg, .png, .tiff]
```

You can use a [LinkedHashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) if you want to preserve the order.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, I would just use `replaceAll` and assuming `String` has always some file extension

```
String ext =  "png,jpg,jpeg,tiff,bmp,cdr";
ext = "."+ext.replaceAll(",",",.");
```

And output is

```
.png,.jpg,.jpeg,.tiff,.bmp,.cdr
```

Answer (score 1):

I solve this with reduce function of stream.

- **First** we split string
- **Second** we add "." to every element
- **Third** we reduce result into single line

```
    String str = "png,jpg,jpeg,tiff,bmp,cdr";
            String result = Stream.of(str.split(","))
                    .map(s -> "." + s)
                    .reduce(" ", (s1, s2) -> {
                        return s1 + "," + s2;
                    });
            System.out.println(result.substring(2,result.length()));
```

This program print  **.png,.jpg,.jpeg,.tiff,.bmp,.cdr**

Comment: There is an extra "," at the beginning of the string

Comment: @HarshalParekh i fixed this with substring function

Comment: Which does not make this an "elegant" solution.

Comment: @HarshalParekh look now pls

Comment: Oh sorry. It's extra comma again(